# class stripe doesn't have checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to get the session object from the session ID.
According to the [API document for Node](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve?lang=node), it can be get by **stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(ID)**

So, I've tried as follows:

```
this.stripe = await loadStripe(MY-CREDENTIAL);
console.log("stripe",this.stripe)
this.session = await this.stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(ID);
```

But this.session object was null, and the printed stripe object by console log indicates that **stripe object doesn't have checkout** as follow:

[image]

Comment: Could you please show how "loadStripe(MY-CREDENTIAL)" function works and how do you obtain "ID" parameter?

Comment: The "loadStripe" is stripe official js library from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js, installed as ```npm install``` and imported as ```import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';```

MY-CREDENTIAL and ID were downloaded from my account of the stripe site.